# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: IDEA while trying to run unit tests in IntelliJ

Tags: java, spring, intellij-idea

Basically, I've been having some issues with intelliJ lately and for the most part I've been able to get them fixed, but today after fixing yet another issue, I just started not being able to run my tests properly.

I tried invalidating caches, removing the .idea folder and reimporting the project, completely uninstalling intellij and removing all files it left behind followed by reinstalling it again, but it just doesn't seem to want to go back to working as it used to.

Every time I run the tests for more than 1 module this is what happens: [image]

I'm just running the normal "Run 'All Tests'" option under intellij's right click menu, nothing fancy.
Tests seem to run fine when I just do 1 module at a time or when I run the tests through maven.
Anyone has any ideas?

Comment: Back up your projects. Nuke IntelliJ and reinstall. That's what I'd do

Comment: Unfortunately already did. Everything is backed up on git but yeah, intellij is being a pain right now.

Comment: Did you nuke all its data too - whether in your home directory or AppData or wherever?

Comment: yup, all of it :')

Comment: Do it again and install if you can a *newer* version *to a non-default location*

Comment: I would nuke IntelliJ, including *every* cache and settings file. Then install [*JetBrains Toolbox*](https://www.jetbrains.com/toolbox-app/) app. That app adds an icon menu to manage installing and upgrading versions of IntelliJ as well as all other products from the JetBrains company.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after a lot of fiddling around I ended up finding out what was causing the issue.

In my specific case, intelliJ was using the "@argfile" option for shorten command line on the junit run configuration.
While this is a java 11 project, for some reason this option that is supposed to be used on java 9+ projects isn't working, and when I switched the option back to JAR manifest the tests started running without any issue.

[image]